# Authentication with OAuth and JWT but without OpenID Connect

Tags: session, authentication, oauth, authorization, openid-connect

I’m wondering if I really need OpenID Connect to provide authentication on top of OAuth2. It seems to me if I generate JWTs (JWE) as my access token and I store user claims, roles/permissions, etc. in the access token, then the OpenID Connect's id token isn't needed. Resource servers can validate the access token on each request. Alternatively, I could keep the access token small and just have it store a session id and populate that session with claims/roles/permission. Also I could put an expiration value in session and support sliding expiration, etc. and not even deal with refresh tokens. Am I missing what OpenID Connect is really about?

**Update**

I just realized I need to clarify my question a bit. If I built a site where I allow users to login via Google, I see how OpenID Connect is necessary. I'm allowing someone access to my site based on some OAuth authorization flow which doesn't prove authentication happened. But if I'm building a bunch of services and I just want to issue tokens to access these service resources, isn't OAuth enough? And if I wanted these tokens to contain roles/claims so I can make authorization decisions in my services, isn't a JWT containing roles/claims enough? If feels like OpenID Connect wouldn't be necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By requiring that the access token is a JWT, agreeing on the user claims that go in to the JWT, putting expiration/issuance timestamps in there and making sure that you cryptographically verify the issuer of the token you're actually doing the very same thing that OpenID Connect is doing: "profiling" OAuth 2.0 in such a way that it can provide user authentication/identity information.

Update:

But if you don't need user authentication semantics you can stick with OAuth 2.0. You may use a JWT as an access token so the Resource Server (the API) can verify and inspect the access token and find out on whose behalf the client is acting. But just be aware that the possession of that token does not mean that the user is present (and authenticated) at that time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just realized I need to clarify my question a bit. If I built a site where I allow users to login via Google, I see how OpenID Connect is necessary. I'm allowing someone access to my site based on some OAuth authorization flow which doesn't prove authentication happened. But if I'm building a bunch of services and I just want to issue tokens to access these service resources, isn't OAuth enough? And if I wanted these tokens to contain roles/claims so I can make authorization decisions in my services, isn't a JWT enough?

Comment: That sounds like standard OAuth 2.0 indeed, where the client presents a structured JWT to the Resource Server (=API) and the API knows how to validate the token and use the claims in there. It does not provide authentication but allows for delegating access to  a client.

Comment: Thanks, that was the confirmation I was waiting for. My colleagues wanted to bring in OpenID Connect and have the APIs consume the id_token. I think it's because they thought claims belong in an id_token (which is backed by a spec) and not in an access token (which isn't defined by OAuth). But since, OpenID Connect, Relying Party (OAuth Client) are the only ones that consume id_token, we'd have to consider our APIs RPs?! That seemed like a misunderstanding of the problem OpenID Connect was meant to solve.

Comment: If you update your answer confirming OAuth + JWT is enough for my scenario and that JWTs containing claims can be used as access tokens, I can accept it. Thanks again!